# Volume encryption status

Tags: macos, encryption

How it possible to determine encryption status of non APFS volume?

For root disk it possible to use `fdesetup status`.
For other APFS volumes it possible to extract from `diskutil info -all` and check field `FileVault`.

But when I create a new volume by using "Disk Utility" it allow me to create "Mac Os Extended (Journaled)" and encrypt it with AES 128 or 256 but.

How may I get encryption status via terminal for such type volumes?

Comment: Use `hdiutil`. HTH

Comment: @CRD
It shows wrong status regarding encryption.
I have created non APFS disk as was described above and encrypted it by AES128.
Response from ```hdiutil``` was next ```encrypted: NO```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from your comment, you will need to provide more information if `hdiutil` does not work for you: macOS version, type of disk image, format of disk image, how you reading the result, etc. With those details someone maybe able to help you.

`hdiutil` has been tested on High Sierra and Catalina with two images, 128 which is encrypted with AES128, and 256 encrypted with AES256, both HFS+. The result on Catalina:

```
% hdiutil info
framework       : 559.100.2
driver          : 559.100.2
images          : 2
================================================
image-path      : /Users/jacksprat/Desktop/256.dmg
image-alias     : /Users/jacksprat/Desktop/256.dmg
shadow-path     : <none>
icon-path       : /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/CDiskImage.icns
image-type      : read/write
system-image    : false
blockcount      : 195353
blocksize       : 512
writeable       : TRUE
autodiskmount   : TRUE
removable       : TRUE
image-encrypted : TRUE
mounting user   : jacksprat
mounting mode   : -rwx------ 
process ID      : 2069
/dev/disk2  GUID_partition_scheme   
/dev/disk2s1    48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC    /Volumes/256
================================================
image-path      : /Users/jacksprat/Desktop/128.dmg
image-alias     : /Users/jacksprat/Desktop/128.dmg
shadow-path     : <none>
icon-path       : /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/DiskImages.framework/Resources/CDiskImage.icns
image-type      : read/write
system-image    : false
blockcount      : 195353
blocksize       : 512
writeable       : TRUE
autodiskmount   : TRUE
removable       : TRUE
image-encrypted : TRUE
mounting user   : jacksprat
mounting mode   : -rwx------ 
process ID      : 2068
/dev/disk3  GUID_partition_scheme   
/dev/disk3s1    48465300-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC    /Volumes/128
```

Both disks have `image-encrypted : TRUE`.

Comment: Sorry, seems that I accidentally have created not encrypted volume.
You are right. I'm able to get the same result

Comment: No apologies required - accidents happen to us all sometimes!